# Oracle Hierarchical queries with views and joins

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table setup like this:

```
create table DEP
(
  depid   NUMBER,
  name    VARCHAR2(200),
  manager NUMBER
);


create table EMP
(
  empid   NUMBER,
  depid   NUMBER,
  name    VARCHAR2(200),
  role    VARCHAR2(200),
  salary  NUMBER,
  manager NUMBER
);

insert into dep (DEPID, NAME, MANAGER)
values (1, 'IT', 2);

insert into dep (DEPID, NAME, MANAGER)
values (2, 'ACCOUNTING', 4);

insert into dep (DEPID, NAME, MANAGER)
values (3, 'MARKETING', 5);


insert into emp (EMPID, DEPID, NAME, ROLE, SALARY, MANAGER)
values (1, 1, 'KEVIN', 'PROGRAMMER', 20000, 2);

insert into emp (EMPID, DEPID, NAME, ROLE, SALARY, MANAGER)
values (2, 1, 'LOUIS', 'ANALYST', 30000, null);

insert into emp (EMPID, DEPID, NAME, ROLE, SALARY, MANAGER)
values (3, 2, 'RACHEL', 'CASHER', 15000, 4);

insert into emp (EMPID, DEPID, NAME, ROLE, SALARY, MANAGER)
values (4, 2, 'JOHN', 'ECONOMIST', 50000, null);

insert into emp (EMPID, DEPID, NAME, ROLE, SALARY, MANAGER)
values (5, 3, 'ERNEST', 'WRITER', 22000, null);

insert into emp (EMPID, DEPID, NAME, ROLE, SALARY, MANAGER)
values (6, 3, 'JACK', 'COMMUNITY MANAGER', 18000, 5);
```

Then I create these two equivalent views

```
create or replace view depemp1 as 
with v as (
 select emp.empid, dep.depid, dep.name depname, emp.name, emp.role, emp.salary,emp.manager
 from emp, dep
 where emp.depid = dep.depid
)
select v1.empid  v1_empid, v1.depid v1_depid, v1.depname v1_depname, v1.name v1_name, v1.role v1_role, v1.salary v1_salary,v1.manager v1_manager
,v2.empid  v2_empid, v2.depid v2_depid, v2.depname v2_depname, v2.name v2_name, v2.role v2_role, v2.salary v2_salary,v2.manager v2_manager
from v v1 ,v v2
where v1.empid = v2.empid


create or replace view depemp2 as
select emp1.empid  v1_empid, dep1.depid v1_depid, dep1.name v1_depname, emp1.name v1_name, emp1.role v1_role, emp1.salary v1_salary,emp1.manager v1_manager
,emp2.empid v2_empid, dep2.depid v2_depid, dep2.name v2_depname, emp2.name v2_name, emp2.role v2_role, emp2.salary v2_salary,emp2.manager v2_manager
from emp emp1, emp emp2, dep dep1, dep dep2
where emp1.depid = dep1.depid and emp2.depid = dep2.depid
and emp2.empid = emp1.empid
```

If I select from them I can check it.

```
select * from depemp1;
```

[image: Results from depemp1]

```
select * from depemp2;
```

[image: Results from depemp2]

Now lets consider the next query to depemp1:

```
select
 level, 
 depemp1.*
  from depemp1
connect by prior v1_empid = v1_manager
 start with v1_manager is null
```

The query above gives no result. Nevertheless, the same query to depemp2 (that gives the same rows and data than depemp1) gives 6 rows.

```
select
 level, 
 depemp2.*
  from depemp2
connect by prior v1_empid = v1_manager
 start with v1_manager is null
```

[image: Result from hierarchical query to depemp2]

I am using Oracle 10g and I don't understand why is this behaviour. I think this hierarchical query works on the same data output from depemp1 and depemp2 and should give the same result.

Comment: Just a note. As far as I remember, Oracle 10g reached end of life in 2013. Are you sure you are using this version of Oracle?

Comment: Yes I am sure. It is an old system that works on that version.

Comment: Please check your views as they do not compile. Your tables do not have `emp.manager` nor an `emp.salary` column.

Comment: Sorry @MT0 I have edited the post. The mistake was on the table definitions, not the in the views.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your results in 18c, I would look for old bug fix notes.  This DBFiddle show consistent results across both queries: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fdc7124f854bc12bba180d2990a836fb)

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue in Oracle 11g [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=549879e3005692cfe3bb97881d687258)